Уменьшение время исполнения кода
Всем привет! Сразу прошу не бить тапками за такой код, главное, что он корректно работает.
Дайте совет, пожалуйста, что можно сделать для того, чтобы сократить время исполнения кода?
Вкратце что делает код :
s - количество списков на проверку, k - число цифр, которые нужно удалить в списках, n - кол-во чисел в списке, mobs_list - сам список
Код по задумке должен удалить k чисел так, чтобы при делении mobs_list на две части (p1/p2) левая сторона была максимально больше, чем правая...
пробовал добавлять штуки по типу : (но это не сильно помогло)
    for _ in range(len(mobs_list)//2):
        n = len(mobs_list)
        if k%2 != 0 and (k>=2):
            k-=2
            if max(mobs_list[n//2::])<min(mobs_list[:n//2:]):
                mobs_list.remove(min(mobs_list[:n//2:]))

p.s. Сначала вроде "красивый", "по всем правилам" код я писал через создание функций, но таким образом я слишком много использовал памяти :(
s = int(input())
answer = []
for _ in range(s):
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    mobs_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
    
    if k == 0:
        answer.append(sum(mobs_list[:n//2:]) - sum(mobs_list[n//2::]))
    else:
        while k != 0:
            n = len(mobs_list)
            if k % 2 == 0: #скрипт для чётных
                keys = [str(key) for key in range(1,6)]
                
                var = dict.fromkeys(keys)
                
                ans = []
                
                # 1 удаляем последние 2 в part_1
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.pop(-1)
                p1.pop(-1)
                p1.append(p2[0])
                p2.pop(0)
                var["1"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))
                
                # 2 удаляем последний в part_1
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.pop(-1)
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                var["2"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))
                
                # 3 удаляем 2 в part_1
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.remove(min(p1))
                p1.append(p2[0])
                p1.remove(min(p1))
                p2.pop(0)
                var["3"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))          
                
                # 4 удаляем 2 в part_2
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                p2.append(p1[-1])
                p1.pop(-1)
                var["4"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))
                
                # 5 удаляем 1 в part_1 и 1 в part_2
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.remove(min(p1))
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                var["5"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))

                
                ind = str(ans.index(max(ans))+1)
                mobs_list = var[ind][0]+var[ind][1]

                k -= 2
                n -= 2
                
                if k == 0: answer.append(sum(mobs_list[:n//2:]) - sum(mobs_list[n//2::]))
                
            else: #скрипт для нечётных
                keys = [str(key) for key in range(1,5)]
                
                var = dict.fromkeys(keys)
                
                ans = []

                # 1 удаляем последний в part_1
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.pop(-1)
                p1.append(p2[0])
                p2.pop(0)
                var["1"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))

                # 2 удаляем первый в part_2
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p2.pop(0)
                var["2"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))

                # 3 удаляем в part_1
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.remove(min(p1))
                p1.append(p2[0])
                p2.pop(0)
                var["3"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))
                
                # 4 удаляем в part_2
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                var["4"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))

                
                ind = str(ans.index(max(ans))+1)
                mobs_list = var[ind][0]+var[ind][1]

                k -= 1
                n -= 1
                
                if k == 0: answer.append(sum(mobs_list[:n//2:]) - sum(mobs_list[n//2::]))

for item in answer: print(item)


Так вам что нужно, память сэкономить или скорость выполнения увеличить?)

@Amgarak время :(

Тогда list не очень вам подходят. Намного быстрее будет если вы полностью построите свою логику через dict\set.

@Amgarak не понимаю маленько... Вот если set я пойму, почему быстрее, то вот dict... Разве употребление словаря не повышает затратность памяти и время обработки больше, чем список?

set это тот же dict только value не хранит, так что концептуально это одно и тоже. А так разумеется set и dict будут зажирать памяти больше, но за счёт своей архитектуры, они куда быстрее list и tuple так как  set и dict  хеширует свои ключи.

Задача про двух японцев всплывает здесь в третий-чётвертый раз за последние дни. Где это её задали?

@MBo ХАХАХАХАХАХХАХАХАХАХАХАХАХХАХАХАХАХАХАХХАХАХАХ, это "олимпиада для начинающих программистов" вроде так называется... Я видел что-то похожее тут на стеке, но там просили именно решение или оптимизацию, хотя комментаторы пишут, что там код даже не робит...

Удаление элемента из списка - дико затратная операция, сложностью O(n). Если это делать в цикле, то сложность уже будет O(n^2). Так что физического удаления элементов из списков нужно точно избегать и как-то строить алгоритм без таких удалений.

@CrazyElf ого... Тоесть время возрастает в квадрате? Учту это, благодарю за подобный ответ.

Для k = 3, a = [4, 1, 5, 3, 6] ваша программа возвращает результат 2. Лучший возможный результат 3 достигается удалением трёх элементов справа. Ваш алгоритм ошибается, оптимизировать его не имеет смысла. Придумайте пусть медленный, но зато рабочий алгоритм. Это необходимо чтобы вы поняли как и где нужно искать ответ.

Прогоним точку разделения списков, начиная с позиции i=m=(n-k)//2.
В левой части на первом шаге удалять нечего, в правой части нужно убрать (из подсчёта, не физически) k наибольших элементов, оставив m наименьших. Считаем разность сумм.
На следующем шаге сдвигаем i вправо, теперь из левой части нужно удалить один наименьший элемент, оставив m наибольших. Из правой части один элемент ушёл влево, поэтому для неё m наименьших  могут измениться (может участвовать элемент, который на прошлом шаге не участвовал в сумме). Считаем разность сумм, сравниваем с имеющейся.
Продолжаем до позиции i=n-m
Остаётся подобрать структуру данных, быструю и удобную для поддержания m наибольших и m наименьших
Ориентир - время O(nlogn), т.е. на указанные обновления должно тратиться логарифмическое время

@StanislavVolodarskiy Ну я надеялся автора подвигнуть на поиск ;-)

Извините. Удалил комментарий. Тут надо подвигать не на поиск структуры, а на поиск верного решения. Если бы кто-то из четверых показал бы что-то работающее, тогда уже можно разгонять до предельной скорости. А так все четверо режут список пополам, и пытаются довести до решения неработающую идею. Как это получилось, что четыре человека пилят одну и ту же ошибку?

@StanislavVolodarskiy Вот и я не увидел ни в одной теме разумного подхода, попытался базу сканирования предложить. Может, кто-то первым эти list[n//2::] предложил, и казалось, что надо только чуть доработать...

@StanislavVolodarskiy вы такой угрюмый... Если человек не имеет опыта в составления алгоритмов или использованиях их в задачах, то почему бы в лишний раз не помочь? Боюсь предположить, что если вы увидите инвалида, которому нужна помощь, то вы пройдёте мимо. Доброта - очень важное качество в человеке и stackoverflow - форум для взаимной помощи, а вы вместо этого пытаетесь показать какой вы "умный" оставляя коментарий : "код не работает". Буду держать в курсе, что не нашёл значений, которые бы не подходили в мой код, а если вы и нашли, то почему бы их не написать в коментарий? Не доволен вами.

@MBo ох... Звучит очень умно хах, попробую реализовать на практике. Спасибо за ответ!
